# Error executing web_service generator from datanoise-actionwebservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionwebservice

I am following [this guide](http://srikanthjeeva.blogspot.com/2009/11/action-web-service-gem.html).

When trying to create webservice with the `generate` script, I get the following error:

```
in 'load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActionController::Request (NameError)
```

Note that I get `::Request`, not `::AbstractRequest`!

Comment: What happens if you try to load the constant `ActionController::Request` from the console?

Comment: Wow, thanks! I added line require 'action_controller' to generate script and that works now! Thanks so much! I thought about adding require already, but I couldn't figure out where)